# How to use p4api.net to get pending changelist number for given submitted changelist

Tags: perforce, p4api.net

Changelist during submission might be re-enumerated. I need to get old changelist number for already submitted changelist. I can do that using p4:

```
p4 -Ztag -F%oldChange% describe 1234
```

I want to do that using p4api.net but I cannot find the way.
Do you know if there is such option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be part of the P4.Changelist interface, but you should be able to just run the `describe` command with tagged output and get the `oldChange` field.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/Index.html

Look at `P4CommandResult.TaggedOutput`, `P4Command`, and `Connection`.